# How to connect to a rethink db hosted on centos?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I have my rethink db hosted in centos and proxied port 8080 to a domain name using nginx.
From my local pc, how do I connect my app to the server?

Answer (score 0):

you need to open 28015 port on your centos server, than you can connect to rethinkdb listening on 28015 port of your centos server via this connection string

```
r = require('rethinkdb')
r.connect({ host: 'centos.example.org', port: 28015 }, function(err, conn) {...});
```

where centos.example.org is hostname/ip of your server.

its worth notice that you should either whitelist your IP in firewall (so, only connections from your home IP is allowed), or install authorization and tls certs on rethinkdb server.

this documents can help -

1. https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/centos/
2. https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/